# Raphaeljs trouble with isPointInside and catching hover events

Tags: javascript, hover, raphael

I'm working on a button that, when you hover over it, expands to shows an image and some text, which need to react to click events differently. It turns out that creating a single hover event over a set of things requires tricky work-arounds, since Raphael will detect a mouse in/out when you change between items within the set. (The original question: [Hovering over a set of elements in Raphaeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224071/hovering-over-a-set-of-elements-in-raphaeljs/) )

The accepted answer in the aforementioned question uses the `isPointInside` function to decide whether a mouse in/out is actually moving in/out of the entire set. It works great with their demo: (blue circle is with their fix, red without)

http://jsfiddle.net/amustill/Bh276/1

However, the red square that appears in this example represents my image, and if you move your mouse quickly between the red square and outside the blue square, the hover out event is never caught. Additionally, mousing over the border of the red square often causes glitching.

http://jsfiddle.net/wTUex/

Why does isPointInside seem to be returning incorrectly? Is there a more accurate function for this I can use?

Comment: This issue occurs because no new `mouseover` event occurs when moving between the red square to outside the blue square quickly. In order for a `mouseout` event to execute, a `mouseover` event has to occur before it but the speed of the cursor movement prevents that. As the author of the original answer, it's an interesting issue to overcome. I haven't had enough time to debug and look in to other solutions, but will hopefully return with a fix soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer (original below)**

Per conversation in comments, you could also assign ids to the boxes and then test, on mouseout, whether the new object under the mouse is or is not the red rectangle, like so:

```
var Paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 400, 300);
var mat = Paper.rect(0, 0, 400, 300).attr({fill: "#CCC"});
mat.node.id = "mat";
// Hover in function
function hoverIn() {
  newBox.show();
  this.text.toFront();
  this.animate({
    height: 140,
    width: 140,
    x: 130,
    y: 80
  }, 100);
}

// Hover out function
function hoverOut(e) {
  console.log(e, e.toElement);
  if (e.toElement.id !== "redbox") {
      newBox.hide();
      this.animate({
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          x: 150,
          y: 100
      }, 100);
  }
}

var rect = Paper.rect(150, 100, 100, 100).attr({fill: 'blue' });
rect.node.id = "bluebox";
var newBox = Paper.rect(140, 90, 120, 120).attr({fill: 'red'}).hide();
newBox.node.id = "redbox";
rect.attr({r:5});    
rect.text = Paper.text(200, 150, 'Hover me!').attr('font-size', 12);
rect.hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chriswilsondc/wTUex/5/)

**Original answer**
I always recommend a different solution: Instead of triggering the hoverOut in a complex set of circumstances, just trigger it when the mouse enters the area outside the box.

See: [How to prevent loss hover in Raphael?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321786/how-to-prevent-loss-hover-in-raphael/14322953#14322953)

```
var Paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 400, 300);
//this should be colored white -- leaving as gray for clarity
var mat = Paper.rect(0, 0, 400, 300).attr({fill: "#CCC"});
// Hover in function
function hoverIn() {
    console.log(newBox);
    newBox.show();
  rect.text.toFront();
  rect.animate({
    height: 140,
    width: 140,
    x: 130,
    y: 80
  }, 100);
}    

// Hover out function
//notice "this" was replaced with "rect" since "this" now refers to mat
function hoverOut() {
  newBox.hide();
  rect.animate({
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    x: 150,
    y: 100
  }, 100);
}

var rect = Paper.rect(150, 100, 100, 100).attr('fill', 'blue');
var newBox = Paper.rect(140, 90, 120, 120).attr({fill: 'red'}).hide();


rect.attr({r:5});

rect.text = Paper.text(200, 150, 'Hover me!').attr('font-size', 12);
rect.mouseover(hoverIn);
mat.mouseover(hoverOut);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chriswilsondc/wTUex/5/)

Comment: Whilst this method works, it's only useful in limited situations. If you start having a more complex Raphael graphic, placing a 'mat' across the entire graphic will only create greater issues. The maintainability of your code will also suffer from not being able to use `this` as intended. Your code could become littered with several `mouseover` and `mouseout` events that essentially do similar things, just to different objects. It's a clever solution, but ultimately not a viable one for bigger applications.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I've yet to find a better solution for the problem that arises from frenetic mouse movements that are too fast to capture mouseout events. Have you?

Comment: Since this question was posted, I haven't had any time to really debug the issue (though it's obvious why it's happening) and work on a solution. Hopefully I'll have that time in the next few days, especially since I'm working on a large Raphael-based application at present.

Comment: How about this: Give the mat an id, keep the hoverout attached to the blue box, and test if the id of e.toElement in the hoverout is "mat":

http://jsfiddle.net/chriswilsondc/wTUex/2/